# Editing date to DD-mmm-YYYY format

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, date

I am looking to format a date in Excel properly using VBA. I have looked at other solutions and it hasn't helped.

I am using VBA to take an entry from the page, format it, then edit it into an SQL string that will go through to an Oracle database.

I need the date to be in DD-mmm-YYYY format, "17-Oct-2017" using today's date.

My code:

```vb
Range("A1").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yyyy"
date= UserSheet1.Cells(1, 1)
```

In the cell, it appears properly, but when I reference the "date" variable in my code, it appears as 10/17/2017.

Comment: Why does it have to be `DD-MON-YYYY`? Oracle accepts multiple data formats including `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: @MT0 you are almost definitely right, but maybe the way my group has the DB configured, it rejects it? I get an error if it isn't presented the other way unfortunately :(

Comment: Please give a [MCVE] including the code you are using to pass the values to Oracle. As it stands it appears to be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that might be solved by fixing how you are passing dates to Oracle rather than putting the date into a different format.

Comment: @Scott Craner's answer fixed it without a problem, so, that is unnecessary. Plus, I don't think it helps to paste in 598 lines of code. As soon as I used his solution, my program worked properly.  Regardless, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. do not use `.Select` it slows down the code.
2. Use the `.Text` to return the text in the cell otherwise you are returning the `.Value`, which is a number, the number of days since 1/1/1900.

so:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yyyy"
date= UserSheet1.Cells(1, 1).Text
```

Comment: Hi, Scott Craner:

Thanks for the answer! I didn't know about just grabbing the "text" from the cell, which seemingly answered my question and solved the problem. Also, thanks for the tip about .Select!